Is every theorem about the natural numbers in ZFC also a first order theorem of PA?
WARNING: My background is that I'm an undergraduate and I've read Elements of Set Theory by Enderton. Thus I do not have a highly technical vocabulary about this topic. But I will try to articulate my question anyway.
If we take ZFC and consider only its theorems where quantifiers range over $\omega$ (e.g. $\forall n\in\omega$ and $\exists n\in\omega$), and then of those theorems take only those whose only non-logical symbols are $\langle+,\times,\text{succ},=,<,0\rangle$, then is this set of theorems exactly the first order theorems of PA?
In some sense, how do we know the arithmetic segment of ZFC is a "conservative" extension of PA? Is there a proof of this? I would expect first order statements of PA to hold in ZFC because those axioms have a model in ZFC. But is the converse also true?
Edit- By first order theorem of PA, I really meant to say a first-order fragment of second-order PA with full semantics

Unfortunately, no. For example, ZFC can prove $\text{Con}(PA)$, but PA can't.

@QiaochuYuan That should be an answer.

@QiaochuYuan that is an interesting answer in and of itself. Are there other examples that do not venture into meta-math?

@PineappleFish Goodstein’s theorem and the Paris-Harrington principle are the most famous examples of that.

That’s a pretty drastic edit, and not what people usually mean when they say “first order theorem of PA”. Aside from the default assumption that PA refers to a first order theory, “theorem” generally connotes provability in some sense, especially seeing how you’re comparing with what’s provable in ZFC. But “full semantics” has nothing to do with provability, and as the answer notes, with this edit, you are just asking about the set of true first order statements in a roundabout way.

@spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for your comment. I simply edited the question to add exactly what I had in my mind when I asked it. I didn't realize that one theory is so much stronger, although that is indeed what I meant so I clarified it. As I said, I've only read elements of set theory by enderton. Whether I asked the "right" question to facilitate my learning is another question.

@spaceisdarkgreen In particular, I thought PA was inherently second order

@PineappleFish All good, didn’t mean to go on a rant there. You got your answer, anyway: second order PA’s arithmetic consequences are actually strictly larger than (first order) ZFC’s. Yea, PA refers to the first order theory by default… there’s  not really a consistent notation for the 2nd order version. I’ve seen $\sf PA_2$.

First I will point out that second order $PA$ with full semantics is categorical, that is, there is exactly one model up to isomorphism. So in particular second order arithmetic with full semantics will be the theory of true second order arithmetic ( I will refer to it as $Th(\mathcal{P}(\omega))$). As a theory it has immense complexity and it determines things like $Con(ZFC)$ but also $\mathcal{P}(\omega)=\mathcal{P}^L(\omega)$. Consequently the first order part of $Th(\mathcal{P}(\omega))$ will be simply the first order theory of true arithmetic $Th(\omega)$ which is also quite complicated, in fact, for any fixed coding of first order sentences in the language $\mathcal{L}_1=(0,S,+,\cdot,<)$, the set:
\begin{equation*}\{n: n \text{ codes a formula } \varphi \wedge \omega\vDash \varphi\}
\end{equation*}
is not definable by an $\mathcal{L}_1$-formula. However, since $ZFC$ is recursively axiomatized and interprets the natural numbers, the theorems of first order arithmetic that $ZFC$ will be recursively enumerable. In particular they will be arithmetically definable ($\Sigma^0_1$ to be specific).
In general, $ZFC$ is a powerful theory in the sense that it makes very bold assertions about the universe and it claims a very large class of functions are in fact recursive. It is however weak since it recursively axiomatized. This is, however, a good thing and I think almost necessary feature.
On the other hand, what most people consider $PA$ to be is the recursively axiomatized theory of $Q$+induction for $\mathcal{L}_1$ formulas. As mentioned in the comments by Qiaochu Yuan, $ZFC$ proves $Con(PA)$. This is because $ZFC$ interprets, as you pointed out, the natural numbers $(\mathbb{N},0,S,+,\cdot,<)$, and it proves that such structure satisfies the axioms of $PA$. It also proves that there exists a truth predicate satisfying the Tarski condition for the structure $(\mathbb{N},0,S,+,\cdot,<)$ and therefore it proves that the theorems of the structure $(\mathbb{N},0,S,+,\cdot,<)$ cannot deduce a contradiction. In particular, it will prove that $PA$ and more will be consistent.
Edit: I probably should mention why there seems to be an apparent contradiction. $ZFC$ asserts that $\omega$ exists and that it has a truth predicate, that is $ZFC$ proves that the set $Th(\omega)$ also exists. It however does not determine it, and will fail to be able to answer some very basic questions about it. In fact, there will be very ugly models of $ZFC$ in which false arithmetic statements will hold. In such models, $\omega$ will be non standard, but will still be a model of $PA$.

How is it possible that $\omega$ is non-standard in some models of ZFC? Doesn't the $\omega$ in any model of ZFC inherit all properties of $\omega$?

Not at all. In particular, a model $M$ of $ZFC+\neg Con(ZFC)$ must have nonstandard natural numbers. The statement $\neg Con(ZFC)$ states that there some $n\in \omega$ which codes a proof of a contradiction starting with the axioms of $ZFC$. But if $ZFC$ has a model no True natural number can exist. In fact the $n\in M$ which codes the proof of the contradiction must be non standard.
